# How do I send an email using Python's "MIME handling package"?

Tags: python, email, mime

Documentation is here for how to send an email: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html

The full code I tried to run was...

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Open the plain text file whose name is in textfile for reading.

# Create a text/plain message
msg = EmailMessage("HI")


# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = "SubjectLine"
msg['From'] = aaaaa@gmail.com
msg['To'] = aaaaa@yahoo.com

# Send the message via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

I get an error at the 16th line of code

```
msg['Subject'] = "SubjectLine"
```

The error is: `'str' object has no attribute 'header_max_count'`

Comment: "*I get an error at the 16th line of code*" ... are you *sure*? This line has absolutely nothing to do with policies and is in line with the guidance from the official documentation.

Comment: Can you explain what you believe the argument you've passed to `EmailMessage` in the line `EmailMessage("HI")` to actually do...? Have you read [the documentation for `EmailMessage`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) to understand what you're *supposed* to pass in as an argument? Can you maybe share the document on which you're basing your understanding that `"HI"` is a valid argument for this function in this context?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will delete this post as revise my question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding on how to instantiate an instance of `EmailMessage`, and it's unclear why you've passed the string `"HI"` as an argument. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) clearly mentions that this argument is meant to take on policy information, which would include the `header_max_count` attribute it seems to expect.

Remove this otherwise unnecessary use of `"HI"` in your code:

```
msg = EmailMessage()
```